# C & python integration

Tags: python, c

When i run this code

```
./call try1 getByteLength '127 89 89'
```

it only accepts 127 as its argument and ignore the rest of it.
[getByteLength] is just name of python function that i am calling from C.

I have use this code from python official page:

How can i do this ?

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
        PyRun_SimpleString("import binascii");
        PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
        PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
        PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
        int i;

        if (argc < 3) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
            return 1;
        }

        //Py_Initialize();
        pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1]);
        /* Error checking of pName left out */

        pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
        Py_DECREF(pName);

        if (pModule != NULL) {
            pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);
            /* pFunc is a new reference */

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
                pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
                for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
                    pValue = PyInt_FromLong((argv[i + 3]));
                    if (!pValue) {
                       Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                       Py_DECREF(pModule);
                       fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                       return 1;
                    }
                    /* pValue reference stolen here: */
                    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
            }
                pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
                Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyInt_AsLong(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
                }
                else {
                    Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                    Py_DECREF(pModule);
                    PyErr_Print();
                    fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                    return 1;
                }
        }
        else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                    PyErr_Print();
                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        }
            Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
            Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
            PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
            return 1;
    }
        Py_Finalize();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `'127 89 89'`, that means the C code gets a single argument (a string with three numbers).

Then you call `PyInt_FromLong((argv[i + 3]))` which takes the address of the third argument and casts that to `int` (the address, it will ignore the *content* of the argument). This is basically a broken random number generator and won't do what you expect or need.

You should use `PyInt_FromString()` instead and use the `pend` pointer to move from one number in the string to the next. Note that you will probably have to skip the white space in the string yourself.

That said, I suggest to use `./call try1 getByteLength 127 89 89` (so you get each number in an individual argument) and then use `PyInt_FromString()` to parse each.

Comment: "This is basically a random number generator." IBTD. The number you get is arbitrary, but far from usable as a RNG, failing most of the requirements.

Comment: can you please give me a example?

Comment: @user2738965: I'm not sure what kind of example you would need. Maybe you should run the code above in a debugger and see what it does?

Comment: I got it. I used PyString instead of PyInt.

Comment: You may want to post the solution here because someone else might run into a similar problem and wonder how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of PyInt, I used PyString. It doesn't need any conversion.

pValue = PyString_FromString(argv[i + 3]);

For other methods, please refer python documentation page.